# AJAX CHUNKED ev

Tags: javascript, ajax, parsing, xmlhttprequest, chunked

On a web site (javascript on front-end), I subscribe to another web site events through a (url) which returns **Chunked data**  .

I want to read and parse only the delta (=new) portion of data received and not all the accumulated content.

Any clever way to do that ? Below my code running well but displaying "all accumulated value"

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
  xhr.open("GET", url, true)
  xhr.onprogress = function () {
    console.log("PROGRESS:", xhr);
}
  xhr.send()
```

Comment: what does that mean? i dont know what data is returned or anything? i dont know how the data is "chunked". i don't know how you're trying to "parse" the data.. too many questions.

Comment: Are you trying to compute upload/download progress of a file? or get the response from the server?

Comment: Chunked stream remains open and send data when they arrive. These data are individual events and I just want to display  THIS event and not all the accumulated flow.